# O Pytesseract não reconhece apenas uma letra

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr

Eu preciso reconhecer apenas uma letra através da biblioteca Pytesseract em python mas o OCR não é capaz de reconhecer quando é só uma letra.

Neste caso, estou tentando reconhecer a letra H, mas nada aparece !

O que posso fazer para que ele reconheça?

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import *
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('H.png',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
img_new = Image.fromarray(edges)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_new, lang='eng')
print (text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_new, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
```

Créditos para a resposta : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119597/pytesseract-does-not-recognize-when-its-just-a-letter